# How to composite two unique series of transparent PNGs?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I have the following two unique series of transparent PNGs:

```
folder1/*-0.png, folder1/*-1.png, folder1/*-2.png, etc.
folder2/*-0.png, folder2/*-1.png, folder2/*-2.png, etc.
```

And I want the output to be the combined images in the parent directory as:

```
*-0.png, *-1.png, *-2.png, etc.
```

Meaning `*-0.png` would be `folder1/*-0.png` overlaid on top of `folder2/*-0.png`.

Here's the script I successfully used to do it with a single pair, but couldn't with a batch:

```
convert folder1/*-0.png folder2/*-0.png -gravity center -composite -format png -quality 100 output.png
```

Comment: `batch` implies a Windows `.BAT` file to me. The tilde (~) implies a Linux/Unix home directory. So I am confused as to what OS you are using. Other than that, I don't understand what you want combined or how it is supposed to look. Please clarify.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I may have worded it incorrectly. I'm wanting to *batch process* my images. Meaning do the same process for all of the images in the two folders as with the script in the last line.

Comment: I'm still unsure what OS you are using.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Unix-based. Why does it matter?

Comment: It matters because different OSes have different shells that interpret/expand things (e.g. ~, %, $HOME, %%TEMPDIR%%) differently and have different tools available, e.g. Perl, GNU Parallel, `bash`, `find`.

Comment: Why has `folder1` become `export` and `folder2` become `export1`. It is all rather confusing. It starts off as `folder1`, then in the second part of the question there is no directory involved and in the final part of the question it is `export1`. And `folder` is a Windows thing anyway, they are called `directories` under Linux/Unix.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry about the folder names. Now cleared up. Do you know how to solve my problem?

Comment: I am pretty certain I will know how to solve the problem once I can understand it - but I am still confused. I can't tell how many directories there are, how many input images there are in any directory, nor how many output images there are, nor which ones belong together. At the moment, I can tell you that `-format png` and `-quality 100` are superfluous in your command and it won't make any difference if you remove them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have two directories (`folder1` and `folder2`) in a parent directory. Both `folder1` and `folder2` contain 300 transparent PNGs named in sequence `*-0.png`, `*-1.png`, etc. I want to overlay the images of `folder1` on top of the images of `folder2` and have the outputs be saved in the parent directory in sequence. Does this clarify it? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: We may be getting there... how many output images will there be altogether? How many input images make up one output image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand, but think you want a `bash` script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd folder1

# Iterate over all PNGs
for f in *.png; do
  this="$f"
  that="../folder2/$f"
  result="../$this"
  echo Combining $this with $that to produce $result
  echo convert "$this" "$that" -gravity center -composite "$result"
done
```

You would save that as `merge` in your HOME directory, then start Terminal and run this command to make it executable (only necessary once):

```
chmod +x merge
```

Then you can use `cd` to go to the parent directory, e.g.:

```
cd where/the/images/are
```

and run the command with:

```
$HOME/merge
```

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you. I mainly was unsure about the proper syntax of all this, but you clarified it for me. This produced the 300 combined PNGs for me in the parent directory.

Comment: Glad we got there! If you need to do this often, just say and I can almost certainly show you how to get it done in parallel tomorrow - it's late here now.